# Grails: Error while applying criteria Query

Tags: grails, nhibernate-criteria

I am applying some criteria query to find the sum of columns and save the result in long format. When there is data in the table,  it is working fine, but in case no match records are found, the following error is thrown:

> Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'long'**

My code is:

```
long referralPoints = ReferralDetail.createCriteria().get {
    eq('referredBy', user)
    projections {
        sum('referralPoints')
    }
}
```

Comment: use a null-check: `get{} ?: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use **Long** instead of **long**. Primitives cannot be null.